# CRM 2013 SP 1 Empty solution in IE10

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

So i just updated my CRM 2013 solution to SP 1.

After doing so everything in the solution disappeared except for the Navigation bar as seen on the attached picture.

This only happens in IE where the server is running IE 10. When opening in firefox i am told there is an error but everything is shown.

It might be interesting to tell that the CRM installation is danish. There are no languagepacks installed, and when i inspect the scripts run i can see an invalidcharacterexception in global.ashx.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try toggling compatibility mode on/off to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I did and that didnt fix the problem.

Comment: Hunt down and remove diacritics from your cod

Comment: Try to install the English language pack, that helps sometimes